# Problema con CreateForm Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy desarrollando una app de práctica, en la cual al crear un producto, en vez de redireccionar hacia donde indica `reverse_lazy()`, salta un **error 404**.

Dejo el view y el url.

views.py

```
class CreateProduct(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
template_name = 'products/create.html'
form_class = ProductForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('products:feed')
```

urls.py

```
path(
    route='',
    view=views.ProductsFeed.as_view(),
    name='feed'
),

path(
    route='create/',
    view=views.CreateProduct.as_view(),
    name='create'
),
```

urls.py de raiz

```
    urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    #   Apps
    path('products/', include(('products.urls', 'products'), namespace='products')),
    # path('shopping_cart/', include(('shopping_cart.urls', 'shopping_cart'), namespace='shopping_cart')),

    #   Local
    path(
        route='',
        view=views.Home.as_view(),
        name='home'
    ),

    path(
        route='map/',
        view=views.Map.as_view(),
        name='map'
    )

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir la URL de `feed` por favor

Comment: @Ceragos ahi lo puse en urls.py!

Comment: Puedes compartir por favor las `url` de la raíz

Comment: @Ceragos agregado!

Comment: No lo uses con el atributo `success_url` en su lugar sobreescribe el metodo `def get_success_url(self)` y retorna `reverse('products:feed')`

Comment: intenta asi  `path('products/', include('products.urls', 'products'), name='products'),`

Comment: @Ceragos no funciona, sigue el mismo problema.

Comment: @JackNavaRow tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te aconsejaría que usases la opción **HttpResponse** en tu función del archivo views.py para redirigirte a tu URL que quieres, sin necesidad de llamar a ninguna otra vista.
Según he leido por Internet, Django incorpora el módulo render, una plantilla fácil de usar para estas cuestiones donde por "debajo" utilizar HttpResponse.

Te dejo el enlace:
[Tutorial Render()](https://openwebinars.net/blog/tutorial-django-vistas-url-procesar-datos/)

Comment: no es lo que ando buscando, en mi otro proyecto si funciono como lo hice, pero no se porque en este no funciona